# Кнопки соц. сетей без подключения сторонних библиотек JS

Tags: javascript

Методом переписок выяснилось, **чтобы пользователи могли именно делиться** кнопки соц. сетей без javascript не установить. Благодарность 
[humster_spb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/212007/humster-spb)
Тогда вопрос стоит так: как установить кнопки соц. сетей **чтобы пользователи могли именно делиться** публикацией-постом, применив javascript у себя на сайте. **Не прибегая к помощи сторонних ресурсов** ???

---

**И что очень важно нужно чтобы были Viber, WhatsApp, Skype, Telegram**

Comment: Просто указываете ссылку на соц. сеть или канал в месенджере

Comment: `<a href="viber://add?number=12345678">Viber</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите, чтобы пользователи могли именно *делиться*, то просто ссылки Вам не помогут - нужен javascript. Есть готовые библиотеки, лично мне нравится [share.js](http://ellisonleao.github.io/sharer.js/) - там много разных соц.сетей и мессенджеров.

Работает библиотека очень просто: создаёте кнопку, в качестве data-sharer указываете соц.сеть, а в качестве data-url - ссылку на материал, которым пользователь может поделиться. Можно также указать заголовок, под которым будет опубликован материал (data-title), и хештег (data-hashtag).

`<button data-sharer="facebook" data-url="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">Поделиться в Facebook</button>`

Здесь скрипт блокируется, воспроизводимый пример можете посмотреть [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/r8ks0u7z/1/)

Comment: @humster_spbСделал правку в вопросе. Прочитайте пожалуйста.

Comment: @Budun, почитал. Вы, видимо, решили, что share.js - это какой-то сторонний ресурс. Вы неправильно поняли :) Это просто скрипт, который Вы можете скачать и подключить на своём сайте (как jQuery или Bootstrap). Я же дал ссылку на jsfiddle, где приведён реальный пример использования этой библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут **href** в тэге **a** задает адрес документа, на который следует перейти. Просто укажите URL ссылку на социальную сеть вместо символа #.

Для того, чтобы указать ссылку на мессенджер, необходимо прописать следующее, изменив номер телефона на необходимый:

```
<a title="WhatsApp" href="whatsapp://send?phone=+120345678910">WhatsApp</a>
<a title="Viber" href="viber://chat?number=+120345678910">Viber</a>
<a title="Viber" href="viber://add?number=120345678910">Viber</a>
<a title="Telegram" href="tg://resolve?domain=nikname">Telegram</a>
```

Comment: @Mary AloshynaСделал правку в вопросе. Прочитайте пожалуйста